# Error In every new project i make . Android . App_Compat_v7

Tags: android, eclipse, parse-platform

I know there are a lot of similar questions asked but my problem didnt solved at all .

Yesterday night i updated my sdk tools , during that an error came that a file cannot be renamed coz its been in use after full updation when i again opened eclipse that sdk was all gone n it was not opening .

So i uninstalled sdk and downloaded latest version of it .

i imported all my projects to it ,Old projects r working fine .

But whenever i m creating a new project it have errors n that is bcoz import appcompat have errors n also their is no app_compat_v7 -app Something in my lib of new project .

Please Help me out , i have given my last 12 hours for this .

Thanks

[image: You can check in image also]

Comment: Use Android Studio, that fixes your problems

Comment: I Have No Experience For That ! How Can i Import all my eclipse files to studio ?

Comment: You actually just have to press "import project" in Android Studio and it opens everything automatically to be compatible with Android Studio. If it is not added automatically, the dependency you need in your build.gradle file is `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'`

Comment: Thanks , Is it okay to switch to studio ? i m not aware of anything in studio . Actually i am new for android

Comment: Official support for Eclipse is ending at the end of the year. If you are new to Android, please start with Android Studio, not Eclipse, at this point.

Comment: Thanks Alot . I am migrating to studio .